# Adapting design to be SOLID

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

I am working on a very large ASP.NET application.  The problem is that there is not a lot of logic behind the design.  The original developer chose about ten classes and that was it.  There is high coupling and low cohesion.  For example, clsPerson holds all the functionality for Person and breakes most of the rules of SOLID.

I have started to incorporate design patterns into my toolkit.  My question is: what is the best way to incorporate badly designed classes into the better design.  For example, if you had a class clsStudent that contained all the Student functionality to date and then created a class called clsUndergraduate then would you simply derive clsStudent? I realise that a lot of this depends on context but I am looking for general guidelines.

There is a lot of information online that talks about SOLID, but not a lot that talks about how to adapt an existing application to be SOLID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be argued that you should only aim to implement SOLID principles as, and when the need arrives. However, I'm an advocate and believe that it's not difficult to add elements of SOLIDity to your design without too much overhead or heartache.

Trying to move an existing model to a more SOLID model can be difficult. I would suggest taking small, manageable parts and gradually refactoring. If you have the safety net of automated tests, this should be achievable with confidence. If not, make sure you fully understand the scope of the changes you are making. It's easy to introduce subtle bugs. Ultimately, serious changes will be likely to introduce new tests anyway.

Complying with the SRP is likely to be the easiest place to start. Try to define the main responsibility of each class. If they currently have more than one responsibility, note them and look at how these responsibilities can be moved out and elsewhere. For example, many 'God' classes will be managing persistence, validation, initialisation, etc. along with business logic. See if you can begin to take the persistence code out and put it into mappers/repositories/etc.

If you do this logically and sequentially, my experience is that, as you go, making lots of mistakes along the way, the relevance and importance of the other principles will emerge and make themselves, sort of, obvious.

I found that as I experimented with SOLID principles, by reading and re-reading (mainly Bob Martin and ObjectMentor) more clarity emerges as you have practical experience of implementation. Don't forget the opening principles defined in the Gang of Four, also. Concepts like 'favour composition over inheritance' go hand-in-hand with SOLID OO principles.

Bear in mind that SOLID code is generally more complex than non-SOLID code and can, therefore, be harder to maintain and debug by those not familiar with it. Skeptics might lay the accusation of 'over-engineering' at your door, which can be difficult to argue against with those who haven't wrestled with enhancing/fixing tightly coupled, incohesive code.

Good luck. Please feel free to ask more as I'd love to hear the input of others on this subject. It's scope is wide and varied.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I have no time to refactor at the moment.  Therefore I am looking at ways of incorporating well written code (using design patterns and SOLID principles) with poorly written classes.  Would you simply isolate the poorly written classes?

Comment: Yes. They're no reason to stop you moving forward with new and better principles.

Comment: Thanks.  Say you have a class (clsPerson) that has a couple of dozen responsibilities and you want to extend it with another responsibility, how would you approach this? I can think of a few ways off hand but I am unsure, which is best practice.

Comment: You could extend it via inheritance and override as necessary or you could 'decorate' it by wrapping your new class around it. Decoration tends to be done with composition which is often more flexible and easier to extend than inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, I am nearly read to finish.  I am interested in your point: "Skeptics might lay the accusation of 'over-engineering' at your door".  What approach do these skeptics use?

Comment: Generally, the approach you're trying to move away from. Highly coupled, incohesive code. Usually long sections of 'script' in a few big classes rather than lots of smaller classes with well defined roles, responsibilities and boundaries.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "generally"? I your experience what proportion of developers code using design patterns and SOLID principles?

Comment: Impossible for me to say. I can only base it on my own, anecdotal evidence.